# three div row layout cordova

Tags: html, css, cordova

all i want is (it should be) very simple...i just want a 3 row layout
each let's say 33.33% of height and 100% width. 
Keep in mind that i insered a slide navigation menu (facebook style)
all that i tested doesn't fit, i tryied to keep fixed the first and the last div (position fixed) and absolute the second but the result isn't what i wanted since the div overlap each other and the last remains bigger that the Others...
my html:

```
<div id="container">

    <!--The Hamburger Button in the Header-->
    <header>
        <div id="hamburger">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--The mobile navigation Markup hidden via css-->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!--The Layer that will be layed over the content
    so that the content is unclickable while menu is shown-->
    <div id="contentLayer"></div>

    <!--The content of the site-->


        <div id="c1" class="ctn1">

        </div>
        <div id="c2" class="ctn2">

        </div>    
        <div id="c3" class="ctn3">

        </div>    

</div>
```

my css:

```
.ctn1{
    z-index: 0;
    background:url(../img/tralicci.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:37%;
    position: fixed;
    top:5%; 
}
.ctn2{
    background:url(../img/paesaggio.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:37%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
.ctn3{
    background:url(../img/skyrim.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:37%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    content: "";
}
```

the result should be responsive (also keep in mind the rotation of the device)
thank you

Comment: Where are the cell classes being used? Not in the markup above.

Comment: why not? i wanted empty div (clickable) with an image as background

Comment: sorry i will correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this achieve the layout you're looking for:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmpwNz

```
nav{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.ctn1{
    background: #333;
    height:33.33%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.ctn2{
    background: #222;
    height:33.33%;
    top: 33.33%;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.ctn3{
    background: #111;
    height:33.33%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro...another little question...if i want the background to fit? :)

Comment: Can you post either real links to the images or the image dimensions so placeholders can be tested?